# An exercise about restarting program when encounter SIGINT

Tags: c, sigint

This is an exercise in "Expert C Programming",I have completed it,but it doesn't work.
The exercise's requirement is as the title says:

**restarting the program when encounters SIGINT in the program rather than simply exiting.(which is Ctrl-C in Linux)**

So my answer is as followed:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
jmp_buf jbuf;
void handler(int sig);
main()
{
    setjmp(jbuf);
    signal(SIGINT,handler);
}
void handler(int sig)
{
    if(sig==SIGINT)
    {
        printf("Program restarting\n");
        longjmp(jbuf,1);
    }
    return;
}
```

When I run this applet,it simply exits and I don't have chance to input 'Ctrl-C',how to fix the applet?

Comment: what you done `main`? your main just return.put `while(1)` in your main at end to stay in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it sleep, so you have a chance to type ctrl-C. Then it works fine:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
jmp_buf jbuf;
void handler(int sig);
main()
{
    setjmp(jbuf);
    signal(SIGINT,handler);
    sleep(15);
}
void handler(int sig)
{
    if(sig==SIGINT)
    {
        printf("Program restarting\n");
        longjmp(jbuf,1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Also, it's recommended to use sigaction instead of signal.

Comment: Both sleep(15) and while(1) are OK,but they can work only once! I know   if I want to make the applet can restart more than once,I have to reset the signal() function,but how to do this exactly?

Comment: The answer from @ttworkhard below addresses that. To be honest, if I have to trap signals, nowadays I usually use either [libev](http://libev.schmorp.de) or [libevent2](http://libevent.org) because I think the code is way cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I think you used the wrong function. It should be **sigsetjmp** and **siglongjmp** when you use signal.Because they can restore signal context.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
jmp_buf jbuf;
void handler(int sig);
int main()
{
    sigsetjmp(jbuf,1);
    signal(SIGINT,handler);
    while(1){
    }   
    return 0;
}
void handler(int sig)
{
    if(sig == SIGINT)
    {   
        printf("Program restarting\n");
        siglongjmp(jbuf,1);
    }   
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program exits when `main` returns, just like any other program.